# DropDownStyle of ComboBox changes BackColor behaviour

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms 2.0 with a couple of ComboBox controls on it. For some of those ComboBoxes the property `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDown`, while others are set to `DropDownList`.

Now, to indicate changes in the selection the property `BackColor` is set to a different value for each ComboBox. Those with the `DropDownList` style have a complete colored background, while those with the `DropDown` style only show a colored frame. I'd like to have the full-colored version for both styles.

I'm working with VS2005 and .NET 2.0.

-UPDATE
I should mention that the `ComboBox` is disabled. While the background is fully colored when it's enabled, it only shows a small colored border when it's disabled. That's what i want to change, i want the complete background colored while the `ComboBox` is disabled.

Comment: Can't you manually set the desired BackColor on the DropDown ComboBoxes in the designer?

Comment: Well, i can set it manually or in code - doesn't make a difference.
I should add though that the effect that i describe occurs only when the ComboBox is disabled! With the Box enabled the background is fully colored, but while it's disabled only a small border is colored.